# How can i achieve this in mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create documents in which two fields should not be duplicated. They should be unique.
for example.

1. {
   "year": "2021",
   "class": "3"
   }
   2){
   "year": "2021",
   "class": "4"
   }
   3){
   "year": "2020",
   "class": "3"
   }
   4){
   "year": "2020",
   "class": "4"
   }

all of them are valid
but
{
"year": "2021",
"class": "3"
}
and
{
"year": "2021",
"class": "3"
}
are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use unique compound indexing on fields "year" and "class".
Eg: `db.collection.createIndex({"year":1,"class":1},{unique:true})`.
This will check for uniqueness on both fields when a new document is being created.

If you want to place a validation in mongoose, then use findOne(),

```
let getData = await yourSchema.findOne({"year":year,"class":class});
if(getData && Object.keys(getData).length){
   return res.json({"message":"Duplicate data"})
}
```